# NLB not created in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, network-load-balancer

I am having following ingress definition

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"TCP": 80}, {"TCP": 9093}]'  # NLB supports TCP only
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: TCP  # Use TCP for NLB
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev-kafka-web.binary-labs.in  # Replace with your domain
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: echoserver  # Replace with your service name
                port:
                  number: 80
```

When I apply this using `kubectl` command, I see a success message but there is no NLB provisioned in AWS console. I tried checking logs for **aws-load-balancer-controller-XXXX** but there are no errors found. What am I missing

Comment: Let's suppose your  ingressclass name for ALB controller is  **alb** .. Can you try to add `ingressClassName: alb` under spec

Comment: NLB is not an ingress provider. It can only be used for service with `Type: LoadBalancer`. ALBs can provide ingress with `aws-load-balancer-controller`.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a Network Load Balancer you don't use ingress that's for ALB, you should use the service directly configured as LoadBalancer type, and  set the annotations to configure it as NLB.

The annotation you have `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"` is correct, but is for the service.

[Here is the documentation](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/nlb/)